# Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa - Can't associate document type with application

Tags: pdf, 20.04, evince

Just migrated from 18.04 to 20.04. 
pdf files were associated with document viewer OK until I installed Vivaldi browser. Since that clicking a pdf file will open it in Vivaldi. 
It is possible to force it - but the option to make it default just is not there. 
in the Settings - Default Applications - there is no option for "document" of any kind at all

my computer is Dell Inspiron and the installation was made "from scratch".

Answer (score 2):

You can change filetype associations by right-clicking a PDF in the file browser, select `Properties` ->  `Open with`

Choose the `Document Viewer` and click `Set as default` and you should be good to go.